# Entity Framework Self Join

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6 with Code First, and I have a table with the following structure:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }}

    public Item Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Item> Children { get; set; }       
}
```

I would like to know if it's possible to get on a single query/trip to database, all `Items` across my tree until the root, supplying a `itemId` as argument.

***e.g Give me all parents from `ItemId` 55 until no parent is found.***

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Probably have to map to a recursive CTE with stored proc.

Comment: Echoing @GraemeMiller here: I had to do something similar recently, and that's how I ended up doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get all parents in one trip using any sane code.

However you can do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11565855/304832

By modifying your entity a bit, you can add 2 derived collections:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }}

    public virtual Item Parent { get; set; } // be sure to make this virtual
    public virtual List<Item> Children { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ItemNode> Ancestors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemNode> Offspring { get; set; }
}
```

You do need to introduce a new entity to make this work though, which looks like this:

```
public class ItemNode
{
    public int AncestorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Ancestor { get; set; }

    public int OffspringId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Offspring { get; set; }

    public int Separation { get; set; } // optional
}
```

Now, if you want

> all parents from ItemId 55 until no parent is found

...you can do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Item> allParentsFrom55 = dbContext.Set<Item>()
    .Find(55).Ancestors.Select(x => x.Ancestor);
```