# Entity Framework load navigation property from cache

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've `Field` entity and I'm looking for a way to load all tree of nested Fields  without multiple DB's queries. I heard about solution with a closure table like on this question [Most efficient method of self referencing tree using Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565423/most-efficient-method-of-self-referencing-tree-using-entity-framework)
But I'm not sure that it's the most simplest way (actually I don't understand how to populate the closure table and map result after query)

Rather than I would like to load all Fields by CommonId but I don't load data from cache by means of navigation properties.

```
public class Field
{
        public int Id { get; s; };

        public CommonId{ get; set;} //each field from FieldDetails has same value

        [ForeignKey("ParentField")]
        public int? ParentFieldId { get; set; }
        public virtual Field ParentField {get;set;} 

        public virtual ICollection<Field> FieldDetails { get; set; } =
            new List<Field>();
}


var allFields = Context.Fields.where(f=>f.CommonId == 1).ToList(); //load all fields in memory cache
Field root =  Context.Fields.Find(1);
foreach (var f in root.FieldDetails)
{
   foreach (var f2 in f.FieldDetails)  // should be loaded from cache instead of DataBase Query
   {
     ... 
   }
}
```