# How to iterate over all child by id in entity framework core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

This is my entity:

```
public class User {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int? ManagerId { get; set; }

        public User Manager { get; set; }
}
```

I have relation on same table with `ManagerId`.

```
builder.HasOne(t => t.Manager).WithMany();
```

I'm using entity framework core and i want to iterate over all child by id.

Example:

```
Id | Name   | ManagerId 
---------------------
1  | Boss   | null
---------------------
2  | Child1 |  1
---------------------
3  | Child2 |  2
```

Input:
1

Output:
2, 3

---

Input: 2

Output: 3

---

**P.S. There can be more than one "Bosses" so i want to filter by id**

Comment: Answer was updated! Pls take a look

Comment: That's not iterating by ID, that's retrieving hierarchical data. The easiest option would be to use a `hierarchyid` field to store the hierarchy path of each entry, not a ParentID. With a parent ID the only way you can retrieve the hierarchy without iterating is to use a recursive CTE

Answer (score 0):

Try this code pls

```
 public async Task<List<User>> GetChilds(int userId)
    {
     List<User> newChilds = new List<User>();
        var childs = await _dbContext.Users.Where(x => x.ManagerId == userId).ToList();

        if (childs != null)
        {
            foreach (var child in childs)
            {
                var childChildreen = await GetChilds(child.Id);
                if(childChildreen != null)
                {
                    newChilds.AddRange(childChildreen);
                }

            }
            childs.AddRange(newChilds);
        }

        return childs;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is optimal solution ?

Comment: You are sending request in database every function call

Comment: Foreach child he runs the same function, using recursivity! Is normal to use recursive functions they have to be well tested and optimized, this one is simple so i think is good solution.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark my answer as useful. Thank you, best regards

Comment: @MateGvenetadze as long as you don't use a `hierarchyid` any solution is suboptimal. Solutions that use iteration are the worst possible case

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos a recursive solution is used in special scenarios only! ofc if he want to have better performance he will have to redo is entities and think in a way that would be easier to retrieve the data he wants.

Comment: @PedroBrito this isn't a special case. [Recursive CTEs](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/) are used to retrieve hierarchical data when a parent/child model is used. That's *not* the same as calling `GetChild` recursively. A recursive CTE is still a *single* query that will return all the data at once. The use of [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-2017) instead of parent/child is a far faster option

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to *iterate* over all emlements you could do something like this:

add a collection of children to your entity

```
public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
```

let the model builder know

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOne(t => t.Manager).WithMany(u => u.Users);
}
```

finally load the tree into memory and iterate:

```
using (var ctx = new DataContext())
{
    // load the whole hierarchy to memory
    var q = ctx.Users.Include(u => u.Users).ToList();
    var user = q.Single(u => u.Id == 1);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", GetIds(user)));
}

private static IEnumerable<int> GetIds(User user)
{
    foreach (var child in user.Users)
        foreach (int id in GetIds(child))
            yield return id;

    yield return user.Id;
}
```

the key is EF cores *relationship fixup* as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41837737/1859022

**Be advised**: perfromance might become an issue pretty quickly for a larger table since your data structure has no way of filtering the tree before loading it into memory. If this is the case you might need to move to [Most efficient method of self referencing tree using Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565423/most-efficient-method-of-self-referencing-tree-using-entity-framework)