# Is there any better way to filter the data based on grand grand child property in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a model which consist multi level of sub models. Now I want to filter the data based on most bottom level of child element. Please see the code (it's just for reference)

```
var treatmentItemss = new List<TreatmentItemViewModel>();

IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> countries = UmbracoContext.Content.GetById(contentId: 1063).Children(); 

foreach (var country in countries)
{
    IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> countys = country.Children();
    foreach (var county in countys)
    {
        IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> cities = county.Children();

        foreach (var city in cities)
        {
            IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> clinics = city.Children();
            foreach (var clinic in clinics)
            {
                IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> clinics2 = clinic.Children();
                foreach (var clinic2 in clinics2)
                {
                    IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> treatmentMenus = clinic2.Children();
                    foreach (var treatmentMenu in treatmentMenus)
                    {
                        IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> treatmentCategories = treatmentMenu.Children();
                        foreach (var treatmentCategory in treatmentCategories)
                        {
                            dynamic treatmentItems = treatmentCategory.Children();
                            foreach (var item in treatmentItems)
                            {
                                treatmentItemss.Add(new TreatmentItemViewModel
                                {
                                    SurgicalProcedure = item.SurgicalProcedure?.Name,
                                    NonSurgicalTreatment = item.NonSurgicalTreatment?.Name,
                                    Title = item.Title,
                                    Id = item.Id,
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In above code I want to fetch the data base on `SurgicalProcedure.Name`
for example, I want to get all the data of countries in which `SurgicalProcedure.Name == "Angioplasty"`.

Comment: so much complexity for what is essentially a straightforward SQL query

Comment: "Please see the code (it's just for reference)" - it doesn't really explain what challenge you're facing though. It's unclear what you mean by "I want to get all the data of countries in which SurgicalProcedure.Name == "Angioplasty"" - what do you mean by "all data of countries" in this case? Are you just looking for a list of countries which have at least one city with at least one clinic which provides angioplasty? Please clarify your question.

Comment: using LINQ `IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> filteredCountries = countries.Where(c => c.Children().Any(co => co.Children().Any(ct => ct.Children().Any(cl => cl.Children().Any(cl2 => cl2.Children().Any(tm => tm.Children().Any(tc => tc.Children().Any(item => item.SurgicalProcedure != null && item.SurgicalProcedure.Name == "Angioplasty"))))))));
`

Comment: @letsdoit, it's very hard to read that code in a comment. You really ought to post a proper answer so that you can format the code. You really ought to post a proper answer regardless.

Comment: looks like you can query `treatmentItems` directly since you need `SurgicalProcedure.Name` in which would give you all data that are applied to every single related table (because it's many-to-many relation). Then, use the results to filter the data as needed (like if you need a specific country, just pass the country id with the query ...etc).

Answer (score 0):

You could consider writing an [iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators) method, that does the dirty job of doing the deep dive in the model, and exposes all the `TreatmentItemViewModel` as an enumerable sequence. Iterators are methods that contain `yield return` statements:

```
IEnumerable<TreatmentItemViewModel> GetTreatmentItems(int contentId)
{
    IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> countries = UmbracoContext.Content
        .GetById(contentId).Children(); 

    foreach (var country in countries)
    {
        foreach (var county in country.Children())
        {
            foreach (var city in county.Children())
            {
                foreach (var clinic in city.Children())
                {
                    foreach (var clinic2 in clinic.Children())
                    {
                        foreach (var treatmentMenu in clinic2.Children())
                        {
                            foreach (var treatmentCategory in treatmentMenu.Children())
                            {
                                foreach (var item in treatmentCategory.Children())
                                {
                                    yield return new TreatmentItemViewModel()
                                    {
                                        SurgicalProcedure = item
                                            .SurgicalProcedure?.Name,
                                        NonSurgicalTreatment = item
                                            .NonSurgicalTreatment?.Name,
                                        Title = item.Title,
                                        Id = item.Id,
                                    };
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could then query this sequence with the [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) LINQ operator:

```
TreatmentItemViewModel[] results = GetTreatmentItems(contentId: 1063)
    .Where(x => x.SurgicalProcedure == "Angioplasty")
    .ToArray();
```

Enumerating all these `TreatmentItemViewModel` entities could result in a lot of garbage, so you could consider defining this type as a `struct` instead of `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Having nested code like this is the not good at all.
I think you should change your design to support unlimited level of tree grandchildren and ancestors.

To understand the topic checkout this [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565423/most-efficient-method-of-self-referencing-tree-using-entity-framework).